# How to detect devices logging into a network?

Tags: java

I was attempting to detect any device (desktop, mobile, tablet, etc.,) that logs into an enterprise network. This is a very dirty code I wrote. The code continuously checks for the connected devices and prints the new ones by checking against a set.

```
public class DeviceDetectAgent {

    private static Set<String> connectedDevicesPast = new HashSet<String>();

    private static void detectNewDevices() {

        private Set<String> connectedDevicesPresent = new HashSet<String>(); // saves all devices detected in the previous poll

        InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        byte[] iPAddress = localhost.getAddress();

        for (int i=1; i<=254; i++) {

            iPAddress[3] = (byte) i;
            InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByAddress(iPAddress);

            if (inetAddress.isReachable(1000)) {

                String device = inetAddress.toString();
                if (!connectedDevicesPast.contains(device)) {
                    System.out.println("New device " + device + "found.");
                }
                connectedDevicesPresent.add(device);
            }
        }

        connectedDevicesPast = connectedDevicesPresent;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while (true) {
            detectNewDevices();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

My objective is to create an agent that detects a device logging into the network. Are there any improvements I can do in my code? I believe my code is too trivial.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should ask question about code reviews over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead. Stackoverflow tries to avoid questions where the answer are based on opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution has the following limitations.

First, device can close ICMP using its personal firewall. In this case it will not respond on ping and you will not see it.

Second, your solution is very slow. Ping may take a second, so you will spend ~4 minutes to complete your loop. Fortunately this problem can be fixed using NIO. Take a look on [this code](http://code.google.com/p/core-java-performance-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/test/java/com/google/code/java/core/socket/AsyncPingTest.java) as an example or check other examples of asynchronous ping.

Fixing the first problem is not trivial. Generally you can think about 2 strategies:

1. try to discover device using other ports and protocols
2. try to catch device when it performs some kind of network activity.

Using other protocols is a bit complicated. Take a look on nmap - tool that already does this. 
Catching other network activity can be done using PCAP or if you are implementing this in java JPCAP. You should however locate your spy in "correct" location in the network. The best is to use network mirroring.

Comment: Thanks AlexR! Are there any other solutions apart from pinging to avoid the device hiding behind the firewall, as mentioned by you in the first point?

Comment: Please take a look on my updated answer.